# How to use same list twice in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, list, where-clause

My SQL query contains a `WHERE` clause looking like this:

```
WHERE 
      name1 in ('Emily', 'Jack', 'James', 'Chloe') 
   OR name2 in ('Emily', 'Jack', 'James', 'Chloe')
```

Note that the same list appears twice, which is quite unsatisfying (and my real list is actually longer).

What would be a better way to write this query?

Comment: It would be better to store `name1` and `name2` in separate rows (in another table).

Comment: Sure it would, but I didn't design the DB. I just have a read-only access.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use arrays and [overlap operator `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html), e.g.:

```
with my_table(name1, name2) as (
values ('Emily', 'Bob'), ('Ben', 'Jack'), ('Bob', 'Ben')
)

select *
from my_table
where array[name1, name2] && array['Emily', 'Jack', 'James', 'Chloe'];

 name1 | name2 
-------+-------
 Emily | Bob
 Ben   | Jack
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a common table expression:

```
with to_check (name) as (
   values ('Emily'), ('Jack'), ('James'), ('Chloe') 
)
select ...
from ...
WHERE name1 in (select name from to_check) 
   OR name2 in (select name from to_check);
```

Answer (score -1):

One method is regular expressions:

```
WHERE (name1 || ' ' || name2) ~ 'Emily|Jack|James|Chloe'
```

This isn't *exactly* the same logic (the name "Emily Doe" would match this logic but not the first), but it might do what you want.