# How to use IN clause with multiple columns on same data in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT c1 from t WHERE c2 IN list1 AND c3 IN list1;
```

I want to combine this query to get something like this:

```
SELECT c1 from t WHERE c2 AND c3 IN list1;
```

Comment: What is [the real problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Comment: If list1 is quite long, and you want to omit mentioning it twice within your query, you might consider using a temp table and subqueries. This might also be positive for the performance.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I think the first way is not good and I wanted something like second one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use arrays and [the operator `<@` (is contained by)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html), e.g.:

```
with my_table(name1, name2) as (
values ('Emily', 'Bob'), ('Ben', 'Jack'), ('Emily', 'James')
)

select *
from my_table
where array[name1, name2] <@ array['Emily', 'Jack', 'James', 'Chloe'];

 name1 | name2 
-------+-------
 Emily | James
(1 row)
```

See also: [How to use same list twice in WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42694612/1995738)